# Can't access dynamic id in my html section using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, shopping-cart, popover

I know javascript and jquery a little. In this code, I create an dynamic id="nm{{product.id}".`

```
<div class="row">
        {% for product in product_objects %}
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="card">
            <img src="{{product.image}}" alt="" class="card-img-top">
            <div class="card-body">
              <div id="nm{{product.id}}" class="card-title">
                  {{ product.title }}
              </div>
              <div class="card-text">
                {{ product.price }} tk

              </div>
              <a href="/{{product.id}}" class="btn btn-warning" name="button">View</a>
              <button id="{{product.id}}" class="btn atc btn-warning" name="button">Add to cart</button>

            </div>

          </div>

        </div>
    {% endfor %}

  </div>`
```

Here is my js section:

```
DisplayCart(cart);
    function DisplayCart(cart){
      //console.log(cart);
      var cartString = "";
      cartString += "<h5>This is your cart</h5>";
      var cartIndex=1;
      for(var x in cart){
      //console.log(x);
      cartString += cartIndex;
      cartString += document.getElementById("nm"+x).innerHTML + "Quantity"+ cart[x] +"</br>";
      cartIndex+=1;
    }
      $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
      document.getElementById("cart").setAttribute('data-content',cartString);
    }
```

But console shows following error: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null**
How I can use the innerHTML functionality to the id?
full script: There is my cart.Cart is a JSON object and use localStorage to store cart.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //console.log("working");
    if(localStorage.getItem('cart')==null){
      var cart={};
    }
    else{
      cart=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
    }
    $(document).on('click','.atc',function(){
      console.log("the atc button is clicked");
      var item_id = this.id.toString();
      console.log(item_id);
      if(cart[item_id] != undefined){
        cart[item_id]=cart[item_id]+1;
      }
      else{
        cart[item_id]=1;
      }
      //console.log(cart);
      localStorage.setItem('cart',JSON.stringify(cart));
      document.getElementById("cart").innerHTML = "Cart("+ Object.keys(cart).length+")";
      //console.log(Object.keys(cart).length);
    });
/*    $(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
    document.getElementById("cart").setAttribute('data-content','<h5>This is your cart</h5>')
  });*/
    DisplayCart(cart);
    function DisplayCart(cart){
      //console.log(cart);
      var cartString = "";
      cartString += "<h5>This is your cart</h5>";
      var cartIndex=1;
      for(var x in cart){
      //console.log(x);
      cartString += cartIndex;
      cartString += document.getElementById("nm"+x).innerHTML + "Quantity"+ cart[x] +"</br>";
      cartIndex+=1;
    }
      $('[data-tog
      gle="popover"]').popover();
      document.getElementById("cart").setAttribute('data-content',cartString);
    }



  </script>
```

Comment: [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp) you can read more about using innerhtml for an ID element. Are you sure that there is also an element with this element ID?

Comment: and what is the result of console.log(x);?

Comment: `DisplayCart(cart);` what's `cart` in this line?

Comment: @Frenchy my console.log output is: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null
    at DisplayCart ((index):237)
    at (index):228

Comment: so the error is normal.. cart is the problem

Comment: @freedomn-m cart is a JSON object.

Comment: Franky, the issue is that `cart` (JSON) combined with `for (x in cart)` is not compatible with `getElementById("nm"+x)`  - `nm+x` will require `x` to match `<div id="nm{{product.id}}"` but without any viewing of `cart` value nor `{% for product in product_objects %}` - there's no way to know other than tell you these are not the same.

Comment: @freedomn-m It sometimes works and sometimes doesn't. I can't figure it out what's wrong!

Comment: @freedomn-m  Here is my full project in [github](https://github.com/riyadh9292/Single-page-ecommerce) . Here you can see that to use the functionality of cart button every time we need to run localStorage.clear() explicitly.